# Is dangling pointer dangerous if never being used?

Tags: c, dangling-pointer

We have already known that use-after-free vulnerabilities could cause the security problems. Since the use-after-free error is born from dangling pointer, my question is that if the dangling pointers are not being used in a program, are they considered safe or benign(not such dangerous)?

Comment: Undefined Behaviors only happen when you execute something bad. It won't cause any harm if it's not being used. But why would somebody keep unused code and that too dangerous-unwanted code in one's base?

Comment: If you're concerned, then just set the pointers to `NULL` after calling `free`.

Comment: I think answers to this question will be primarily opinion-based, which does not fit the format of this site well. As such, I'll vote to close the question. One of the other StackExchange sites might be a better venue for it. Sorry about that.

Comment: choice only one language

Comment: If the pointer isn't used after `free` is doesn't matter whether the pointer is left with it's "before free" value or assigned `NULL`. The arguments for always doing `free(ptr); ptr = NULL;` is related to situations where the pointer **is** used again (by mistake, that is). If you know for sure, the pointer is **never** used, there is no problem at all in leaving it with the "old" value.

Comment: It depends somewhat on what you mean by "used".  Clearly, dereferencing such a pointer is undefined behaviour.  Assigning its value to another pointer variable could be problematic as well.

Answer (score 6):

A unused dangling pointer is not dangerous...until the next developer uses it.
You tagged the question as C and C++; I'll consider you work with C++, not C.
For C++, avoid raw pointers with obscure semantics, and dangling tendencies. Using `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can help you a great deal there.

Anyway, avoid dangling pointers. It costs nearly nothing to set a deleted pointer to `nullptr` and it can save tons of dev/debug time.

If you face the problem of dangling pointers, or at least the question associated with them, you probably have there an opportunity to apply the beautiful `rule of zero`: either your class manages memory (you are writing a container, a specific cool fancy pointer wrapper or the like), or you are writing a non-managing class that should not own any raw pointers.

Comment: a dandling pointer can come from various situation. two pointers can contain the same value, and when you free and set one to NULL, you will still have this second pointer who is dandling. Set to NULL is just a stupid solution.

Comment: @arrowd: question was tagger 'c' and 'c++'.
I let the c++ part answer here, for completness

Comment: Thank you! I agree that dangling pointers nullification is a good idea in some cases.But actually, I am trying to write something to detect dangling pointers and uaf error so I need to consider different situations when people make mistakes in their code.

Comment: @Stargatter: 'stupid' is a bit exaggerated, furthermore I did not suggest that. Also, your design is flawed if you have dandling pointers everywhere. The NULL solution is not stupid, it's just not a solution. A real solution is a cleaner design and proper memory management.

Comment: @XyLuo, C does not define a way to recognize dangling pointer values from the values themselves.  It invokes undefined behavior simply to read such a pointer value from a variable.

Comment: @XyLuo There are already tools to detect the use of dangling pointers, e.g. [tag:valgrind]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with non-owning raw pointers on c++ and even in c it's usually not the ones that are used to free the memory that are dangling, because most people set them to NULL directly afterwards.

Comment: @user3386109, Oh yes yes. I am writing a small plugin for another analysis platform and I am not sure should I throw error message for such never used but dangled pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Though you frame your question in terms of security and vulnerabilities, I think the more compelling reason to avoid avoid dangling pointers is to help programs fail early.

Setting pointers to `NULL` or `nullptr` when their referants are eliminated creates an easily-recognized error condition that is *likely* to cause failure as soon as the program tries to deference the pointer. Allowing the pointer to persist in refering to deallocated memory may cause difficult-to-debug conditions later.

In C++, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, and the like can help you avoid issues arising from dangling pointers.

In both C and C++, [address sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) can help you find memory abuses such as inappropriately deferenced pointers. In clang, gcc, clang++, and g++ you can use this tool by adding the `-fsanitize=address` flag to your compilation options (note it does not yet play well with multi-threading).